# Manually decrypting an authorization code throws defuse crypto error

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm using laravel 6.0 and passport 8.0. I listen for the access token to be created and and am trying to manually decrypt an authorization code like so:

```
try {
    $authCodeRaw = request()->input('code');
    $authCode = Crypto::decrypt($authCodeRaw, app('encrypter')->getKey());
} catch (EnvironmentIsBrokenException $e) {

} catch (WrongKeyOrModifiedCiphertextException $e) {

}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Key expected
>   for argument 2. String given instead. in file
>   /var/www/html/vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/Crypto.php on line 103

Comment: The second parameter must be an instance of the [`Key`](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/blob/master/src/Key.php) class, but apparently `app('encrypter')->getKey()` returns a string. If `app('encrypter')` is/returns an instance of `Key` already(?), then just pass that.

Answer (score 0):

It's expecting a [`Key`](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/blob/master/src/Key.php) object, but you have provided a String as suggested by @misorude.

`app('encrypter')->getKey()` seems to return a String, hence, you could create a Key object with that:

```
$key = \Defuse\Crypto\Key::loadFromAsciiSafeString(
    app('encrypter')->getKey()
);
```

You could now pass the `$key` to the decrypt method as follows:

```
$authCode = Crypto::decrypt($authCodeRaw, $key));
```

Hope it helped you!

Comment: When doing that I get this error: Defuse\Crypto\Exception\BadFormatException: Encoding::hexToBin() input is not a hex string. in file /var/www/html/vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/Encoding.php on line 66